# Search tweets between each hour...using twitter Search API

Tags: twitter

Can anyone let me know of the query to fetch tweets containing a certain hashtag say #Twiterrati between 9 AM and 10 Am and so on for every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use Cron job that uses twitters search function.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

Depending on your language, set the cron to run at 9am or 10am. Have a function that calls the Twitter API by doing the following:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#Twiterrati

Remember that you will needed an authenticated twitter app to do the search.

Comment: i need a search query to do that..we only have a search query that does for each day..

Comment: ?q=#Twiterrati is your search query .

Comment: can you let me know how to find the time of the tweet or no of tweets with the given hashtag between 9 Am and 10 AM.

Comment: Oh sorry, you want to find a tweet between that, and not post at that time. Twitter doesn't have time searching between specific time frames that are that process. So you have to search the tweets, parse them, and determine in your code if that was tweet was made between 9 - 10am. The field you are looking for is "created_at".

Comment: You can still do a cron (Linux) or Scheduler (Windows) job, like ashwinsakthi suggested, at 10:01am and do a search and page until you get to 9:00am. Here's how you do the paging: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines.